# Sample java code for adding extension attributes using SCIM for Wso2

Tags: wso2, scim, scim2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to Wso2 IS , currently I am working on adding new extended attributes into WSO2 for user creation however I could not find any example which shows how to do that using Java.

The one I see https://github.com/wso2/charon/blob/master/modules/charon-samples/src/main/java/org/wso2/charon3/samples/user/sample01/CreateUserSample.java looks plan Java code without any SDK and does not help me on how to add extended attributes.

Please share any information which can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any code-level changes to extended scim attributes.Ypu have to define attribute definition in `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/scim2-schema-extension.config` file and do the scim claim mapping to a local claim.

Official docs: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#extending-the-scim-20-api

Detailed blog: https://anuradha-15.medium.com/how-to-add-scim-extended-attributes-in-wso2-identity-server-71621f62c5d3

Comment: Thanks, I was looking examples on how to I pass the extended scim attribute via scim client sdk, the config file changes I have done.